# How to use switch and console.log?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, console.log

I am setting up greetings based on the time of the day and writing them to console using the log() method.

I have tried them in the following two ways

```
const now = new Date(); //Display's Date

switch (true) {
    case (now <= 12):
        console.log("Good Morning");
        break;
    case (now > 12 && now < 16):
        console.log("Good Afternnon");
        break;
    case (now >= 16 && now < 20):
        console.log("Good Evening");
        break;
    case (now >= 20 && now <= 24):
        console.log("Good Night");
        break;
}


switch (now <= 12) {
    case true:
        console.log("Good Morning");
}
switch (now > 12 && now <= 16) {
    case true:
        console.log("Good Afternnon");
}
switch (now >= 16 && now <= 20) {
    case true:
        console.log("Good Evening");
}
switch (now >= 20 && now <= 24) {
    case true:
        console.log("Good Night");
}
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: If you want to write stuff in the style of an `if` statement, then use an `if` statement. `switch` isn't designed to work like that.

Comment: Yes, Kindly Help me in setting up Wishes based on Time in Java Console

Comment: @RavuruBhargav — Stackoverflow isn't a good place to post vague requests for help. Try asking a specific question.

Comment: Yeah I have gone through it, but i need the result from "Switch", Thanks


I am a new learner in Java Script, Sory for the vague request @Quentin

Comment: Why the downvote? The guy has a real question and has provided the code he tried with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the hours first and then take the first approach and remove the previously made checks, because these checks are superfluous.

```js
const now = new Date().getHours();

console.log(now);

switch (true) {
    case now <= 12:
        console.log("Good Morning");
        break;
    case now < 16:
        console.log("Good Afternoon");
        break;
    case now < 20:
        console.log("Good Evening");
        break;
    case now <= 24:
        console.log("Good Night");
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nina " .getHours() " is my error, thanks for helping.

The FIrst two codes which i have mentioned have also worked when i inserted ".getHours()" , Thanks Once Again

Answer (score 1):

`switch` statement won't work for you, try plain `if`:

```
const hours = (new Date()).getHours();

if (hours <= 12)
  console.log("Good Morning");
else if (hours > 12 && hours < 16)
  console.log("Good Afternnon");
else if (hours >= 16 && hours < 20)
  console.log("Good Evening");
else
  console.log("Good Night");
```

Comment: It Worked, Kindly Check the above Answer, Thanks for your Suggestion